# org-latex-preview fail to produce images (org-preview-latex setting problem)

Tags: org-mode

my setting (Org mode version 9.6.6)

```
(setq luamagick '(luamagick :programs ("lualatex" "convert")
                                  :description "pdf > png"
                                  :message "you need to install lualatex and imagemagick."
                                  :use-xcolor t
                                  :image-input-type "pdf"
                                  :image-output-type "png"
                                  :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
                                  :latex-compiler ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f")
                                  :image-converter ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %f -quality 100 %O")))
(add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist luamagick)
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luamagick)
```

Org Preview LaTeX Output show

```
convert: unable to open image `../../../../tmp/orgtexFznXdO.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2874.
```

I think the problem is relative path incorrect.
I did find the pdf file produced by lualatex under /tmp
I try to run convert command manually and it works.
The file I run the command from is located in a symbolic linked directory. Linked from /a/b/c/d/e/ to /A/B/C/D/.
/A/B/C/D/../../../../tmp/orgtexFznXdO.pdf does exist, but not /a/b/c/d/e/../../../../tmp/orgtexFznXdO.pdf
I move the directory to a "matching level", and preview works.
But can I change the setting to use absolute path?

Comment: Please add to your question the version of Org mode that you are using (`M-x org-version`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: you can achieve absolute paths by changing `%f` -> `%F`, and thus:

```
(setq luamagick '(luamagick :programs ("lualatex" "convert")
                                  :description "pdf > png"
                                  :message "you need to install lualatex and imagemagick."
                                  :use-xcolor t
                                  :image-input-type "pdf"
                                  :image-output-type "png"
                                  :image-size-adjust (1.0 . 1.0)
                                  :latex-compiler ("lualatex -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %F")
                                  :image-converter ("convert -density %D -trim -antialias %F -quality 100 %O")))
(add-to-list 'org-preview-latex-process-alist luamagick)
(setq org-preview-latex-default-process 'luamagick)
```

I *just* got bit by the same issue, but using `dvipng`. I was trying to preview latex fragments that were in an org file stored on google drive, and because I'm on a Mac, the path involves symlinks.

Under the hood, the relevant function is `org-compile-file`, which uses `file-relative-name` to generate what will be substituted for `%f`, and it seems that `file-relative-name` doesn't handle symlinks very intelligently. Fortunately, `org-compile-file` also generates an absolute path (using `file-truename`). Per the documentation for `org-compile-file`, this is available with `%F` to signify full name of source file. Unfortunately, the documentation for `org-preview-latex-process-alist` lacks mention of `%F`.

In general, it seems like it would be more sensible for `org-preview-latex-process-alist`'s defaults to use `%F` throughout rather than `%f` since the latter are more brittle.

As a side note, `luatex` doesn't fall down, but only because you get lucky here: it tries to resolve the input path within the output-directory, and you have enough `../`'s to get back to the root (and probably more, e.g., `/../../..` will resolve to `/`), and then it descends properly.